# Set Background color of listview groupview and childview using selector?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, css-selectors

Hi in my fragment am using expandable list view .My question is how to set background color of expandable listview's group view and child view color using selector in android.for ex if user clicks on group view should highlighted with red color and if child view is selected   should highlighted with blue color.I knew it for listview using selector as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_selected="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

can anybody tell me for expandable list view selection.Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible to have selector for both views(group and child) with different states and different colors???

Comment: I think you have to handle both separately.

Comment: @Dynamo if u have any solution can you guide me

Comment: Hi. Any solutions found? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created similar using following code...

list_rowGroup.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ExpandView"


 >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="252dp"
    android:layout_height="422dp"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
    android:textColor="#DB0F31" 
    android:background="#A9ABA6"
   android:smoothScrollbar="true"

    >
</ExpandableListView>
```

lisrrowDetails.xml

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="40dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/apple" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/check"
    android:layout_weight="0.86"

    android:text="@string/check" />
```

activiyt_expand_view

```
CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:gravity="left"
android:paddingLeft="32dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"


android:textSize="14sp"
android:textAlignment="textEnd"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#FA0557"
android:background="#C7BDC0"
 />
```

Group_indicator.xml

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/down_ic"
            android:state_empty="true"/>
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/up_ic"
            android:state_empty="false"/>


    </selector>
```

Comment: Hi thanks @nit but am not asking about group indicator.If i select row in expandable listvieew that should be highlighted.